# PERL Regex to find specific string NOT ending with a period

Tags: regex, perl

For some reason, I am having brain block. I cannot figure out how to match all specific strings that do not end in a period. Take the following text:

```
This has a BR string and another BR but this BR has a period: BR.
```

I want to match ALL `BR` strings but not any `BR` strings that end in a period (`BR.`)

Please help. I know this is easy - maybe it is a different in Perl regex I just am not familiar enough.

Comment: `$string =~ /BR(?!\.)/` perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\bBR(?!\.)
```

`(?!\.)` is negative lookahead to make sure a `BR` is not followed by dot.

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rO5qW2/1)

Comment: Look around assertions are a massively powerful part of the regex engine. Well worth getting proficient with: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html